# Analytics segments with OR conditions show too few sessions

Tags: google-analytics

I've created a segment in analytics with an OR condition like so:

[image: Analytics segment]

However it's not showing the correct number of sessions. The number of unique pageviews for just one of the pages (ie. the number of sessions containing visits to this page) far exceeds the number of sessions shown.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The first possible culprit I would check is "exactly matches" - should it be a looser match type? With more information I might have more suggestions - what do these pages look like in your pageview report table? When you say "far exceeds" do you mean the pageviews are 300 more than the segment sessions? Twice as many? Ten times as many?